A few questions on BRC20
I'm testing BRC 20 tokens on bitcoin testnet and there are some points I don't understand.
1 => It seems tokens cannot share a common name. For example, there cannot be two different BRC 20 token deployments whose tickers are "ordi". How does the system know this?
2 => Also, I inscribed the minting script {"p":"brc-20","op":"mint","tick":"ordi","amt":"1000"} and successfully recorded on the blockchain network (that is, reveal transaction). "ordi" token has already been fully minted on testnet and even though the transaction was successful, no amount of ordi tokens was dropped into my wallet. How does the system know this?
Are there some kind of verification algorithms/checking processes for BRC 20 tokens on bitcoin source code? If so, where can I see them?

I believe BRC-20 software keeps track of precedence and gives priority to those who first deploy a token name. But the inner workings of BRC-20 are off topic here, Only their effect on Bitcoin is relevant to this specific  Bitcoin question and answer website.


Are there some kind of verification algorithms/checking processes for BRC 20 tokens on bitcoin source code?

The  source code of Bitcoin core has no knowledge whatsoever of BRC-20
This is true of many other Bitcoin node software implementations.
You need BRC-20 software if you want to assign meaning to data hidden inside Bitcoin transactions.

Thanks. So BRC 20 is a consensus reached among the public (irrelevant to bitcoin core) on how to interpret the witness data written in a specific format?

I believe that is correct.
